# Maximizer of a continuously differentiable lies on the boundary

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $ G\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ a bounded domain $ f:\overline{G}\to \mathbb{R}^n $ a vector field which continuously differentiable on $ G $ and continuous on $ \overline{G} $. Furhrtmore for all $ x\in G $ it is $ Df(x)\in GL_n(\mathbb{R}) $. Let $ \|.\| $ an arbitrary norm on $ \mathbb{R}^n $. Then $ \max\limits_{x\in \overline{G}}\|f(x)\|=f(\tilde{x}) $ with $ \tilde{x}\in \partial G $.

I was able to show the existence of a maximizer:

Because $ \overline{G} $ is closed and bounded by Heine-Borel the set $ \overline{G} $ is compact. Because $ f $ is continuous on $ \overline{G} $ there exists a point $ \tilde{x}\in \overline{G} $ with $ \max\limits_{x\in \overline{G}}\|f(x)\|=f(\tilde{x}) $. But how can I show $ \tilde{x}\in \partial G $?

Comment: What would $Df(\tilde x)$ be at a maximum $\tilde x \in G$?

Comment: It applies $ Df(\tilde{x})=0 $

Comment: Exactly. And what is $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Indeed $ Df(\tilde{x})=0 $ it is not invertible.

Comment: As written this doesn't quite make sense. Clearly $||f(x)||$ is a scalar quantity, so it's maximum cannot be attained by $f(\tilde{x}) \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Maybe you also mean to include the norm i.e. $||f(\tilde{x})||$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $g(x) = \| f(x)\|$. $g$ is differentiable on $G' = \{x\in G|f(x)\neq 0\}$ and there, its differentialis :
$$\forall x\in G',\forall h \in \mathbb R^n, Dg(x)\cdot h = \frac{1}{g(x)}\langle f(x),Df(x)h\rangle$$

If $g$ was maximal at some point $\tilde x\in G$, then $g(\tilde x) >0$ (otherwise $f$ is uniformly zero, which cannot be) and $Dg(\tilde x) = 0$. This implies that $(Df(\tilde x))^T f(\tilde x)=0$ and, since $Df(\tilde x)$ is invertible, that $f(\tilde x) = 0$, which is absurd.

Therefore, $\tilde x \in \partial G$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f$ is differentiable, and $Df$ is invertible, in the neighborhood of any point $x \in G$ $f$ behaves like its derivative $Df$. Now, $Df$ is linear and it is simple to show that on any line segment it has to take values bigger than at its center.
So, $f$ can not take max inside $G$. However, as you indicated, it has to have max on $\overline{G}$.